# Good UX/UI workshops (continent)

Tags: training

I’m working in an ad agency and looking for good UX/UI trainings.

Since the trainings are for professional graphic designers at the agency, its not necessary to start at the very basic of graphic design but it would nice if the workshop would transfer knowledge from print to the web/digital media.

The trainings should be on the continent; preferable in Austria, Germany or Switzerland.
I’d be happy to hear your suggestions!

Comment: This isn't a great fit for SE, since it isn't really an answerable question. I'd ask at the [UX Slack group](https://userexperiencedesign.slack.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In Germany [artop](http://www.artop.de/seminare) might be interesting for you.
Besides that there's a [blog article](http://www.germanupa.de/aktuelles/blog/mit-aus-und-weiterbildung-zum-usability-ux-experten-die-wichtigsten-programme-vorgestellt.html) from the German UPA about different usability trainings in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I found Norman Nielsen Group events really good. There's one in Amsterdam next May.

http://www.nngroup.com/training/